# Error calling api Angular Spa with .NET Core on deployment

Tags: c#, angular, api, asp.net-core, iis

I created a project with .NET Core for my API and Angular for my frontend. I created this project using Visual Studio with this option checked :
[image: Screenshot of creation]
While I'm developing, everything is working fine but when I'm on my deployment machine running Windows Server 2012 and IIS, my api calls no longer work.

Here's my controller :

```
[Route("api/")]
[Authorize]
[ApiController]
public class RequestController : ControllerBase
{
[HttpPost]
[Route("EvalPassword")]
public async Task<DtoResponseEvalPassword> EvalPassword(DtoRequestEvalPassword request)
{
    return new DtoResponseEvalPassword()
    {
        Score = (int)await _passwordService.EvalPassword(request.Password, request.Lang)
    };
}
```

Here's my Startup.cs :

```
using MaSecurite.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

namespace MaSecurite
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(IPasswordService), new PasswordService()));
            services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(IPassphraseService), new PassphraseService()));
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
            });
        }


        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");

                app.UseHsts();
            }

            JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
            };

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            if (!env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
            }

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
                // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Here's an example of one of my api call (EvalPassword) :

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private translateService: TranslateService, @Inject('BASE_URL') public baseUrl: string) { }

evalPassword(password: string): any {
  const dto = new DtoRequestEvalPassword(password, this.translateService.currentLang);
  return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'api/EvalPassword', dto);
}
```

What I find weird is that everything working really fine in dev. 
In prod, the "angular" works well but every API call I made return :

```
POST https://localhost/api/EvalPassword 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Comment: I suggest you could check the server's event viewer or add the development enviroment varaible into the web.config to see the details error message.  We need the details error message to find the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by enabling Windows Auth on my IIS Server. I thought it was already enabled. :') To see what my error was, I simply put in my Startup.cs :

```
app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
```

for the production's environment.